# Issue Embedding ESRI Swipe Map into Story Journal Map

Tags: arcgis, esri

### What I'm Trying to Do

I'm using [ESRI Story Journal Maps](https://storymaps.arcgis.com/en/app-list/map-journal/) for a lot of it. I've tested extensively on a trial ArcGIS account and everything runs smoothly. One key feature of the apps we're building is to embed another app, specifically a Swipe Map, into the Story Journal. Please refer to [this mockup](http://arcg.is/1T8izR0).

As you can see, 2,3, and 4 all work fine. Those are "Swipe Maps", another ESRI Story Map App. They're added to the Journal Map by adding them as webpage content and appending the `&embed` parameter, as outlined in [this ESRI help topic](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/05/29/embed-story-map-in-story-map/). Those three swipe maps are all hosted on a trial account I set up.

### The Issue

The final slide was added in the same manner but its source is hosted on the content of `New_Account`. You can see in [this link](http://ucsc.maps.arcgis.com/apps/StorytellingSwipe/index.html?appid=749230f9e7a04b06a80596c7414db4b6) that the swipe map works fine by itself. It's only when attempting to load it within the Story Journal Map that it fails to load.

### Troubleshooting Steps I've Taken

I thought that the issue might be with the data in some way. I used [ArcGIS Online Assistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com) to migrate all my data from the trial account, `Old_Account`, to `New_Account`.

- I downloaded a feature layer from as a shapefile from `Old_Account` through the web interface and uploaded it to `New_Account` then created a new swipe map and embedded it into my Journal Story Map. No change
- I embedded a swipe map from `Old_Account` into the Story Journal Map I'm building on `New_Account`and it worked fine. I then embedded a swipe map I created on `New_Account` into a Story Journal Map on `Old_Account` and it did not work.
- I created a new service on ArcMap Desktop and uploaded it to `New_Account` and created a new swipe map with that. Still doesn't work.

I've naturally enabled public sharing for all items involved.

I'm at a loss for what the issue is. I contact you in some hope that there is a permission hidden from me as a user that can be switched on or something by the admin.

Comment: Embedding the Swipe Map into another webpage and linking to that also does not work.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201063

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an https issue.  The last slide shows the following in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://tombottrial.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapJournal/index.html?appid=6525cfa9c33d4e7a9e00fc5cbbec53bc' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 
'http://ucsc.maps.arcgis.com/apps/StorytellingSwipe/index.html?appid=749230f9e7a04b06a80596c7414db4b6&embed'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Try requesting the last as https.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!